# Show that $H=A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, symmetric-groups

> For $n>1$
>   ;
>
> Let $H$ be the set of all permutations in $S_n$ that can be expressed as a product of a multiple of $4$ transpositions .Show that $H=A_n$

**ATTEMPT**:

We know that $A_n$ is generated by $3-$ cycles .

Now $H\subset A_4$ since every element of $H$ is a product of even number of transpositions.

Now take any $\alpha\in A_n$ then $\alpha$ is a $3$-cycle or a product of $3$ cycles.

If $\alpha$ is a product of $3$ cycles of the form $\alpha=(x_1x_2x_3)\ldots (y_1y_2y_3)$ then $\alpha=(x_1x_3)(x_2x_3)\ldots (y_1y_3)(y_1y_2)\in H$.

**Problem**:

If $\alpha$ is a $3-$ cycle then $\alpha=(x_1x_2x_3)$

If $\alpha\in A_3$ and if we suppose  $\alpha=(123)$ in $A_3$ then how can we write $\alpha$ as a product of $4$ $2-$ cycles?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since $n=2, 3$ are allowed, I presume there is no requirement that the transpositions should be distinct?

For large enough $n$, if distinctness is required within each four, and for any $n$ if it is not, when you multiply $(a b)(c d)(e f)(g h)$ by $(g h)(e f)(c d)(x y)$ you get $(a b)(x y)$ - an arbitrary product of two transpositions.

Without distinctness you can also write $(a b)(x y)=(a b)(c d)(c d)(x y)$ for an arbitrary $(c d)$

Comment: But you did not say how to write $(123)$ as a product of 4 2-cycles in $A_3$

Comment: @Maths_Student Depending on which way you multiply cycles (assuming you start with the right-hand one first) try $(12)(12)(12)(23)$ - but this is not a factorisation in $A_3$ since $A_3$ contains no transpositions.

Comment: So $(123)=(13)(12)=(12)(12)(13)(12)$ just this only

Comment: You could have also $(12)(13)(12)(13)=(132)^2$ if you want to avoid the obvious cancellation.